Use one column to group rows and the minimum of another column to order
I'm using kysely client to connect to a Postgres database, but you can also provide the solution in plain SQL.
You can understand the database structure by looking at this migration function:
await db.schema
  .createTable("BigPaint")
  .addColumn("id", "uuid", (col) =>
    col
      .primaryKey()
      .defaultTo(sql`gen_random_uuid()`)
      .notNull(),
  )
  .addColumn("createdAt", "timestamptz", (col) =>
    col.defaultTo(sql`now()`).notNull(),
  )
  .addColumn("name", "text", (col) => col.notNull())
  .execute();

await db.schema
  .createTable("Inspiration")
  .addColumn("id", "uuid", (col) =>
    col
      .primaryKey()
      .defaultTo(sql`gen_random_uuid()`)
      .notNull(),
  )
  .addColumn("createdAt", "timestamptz", (col) =>
    col.defaultTo(sql`now()`).notNull(),
  )
  .addColumn("bigPaintId", "uuid", (col) =>
    col.references("BigPaint.id").onDelete("cascade").notNull(),
  )
  .addColumn("traitId", "uuid", (col) =>
    col.defaultTo(sql`gen_random_uuid()`).notNull(),
  )
  .addColumn("content", "text", (col) => col.notNull())
  .execute();

await db.schema
  .createIndex("Inspiration_bigPaintIdIndex")
  .on("Inspiration")
  .columns(["bigPaintId"])
  .execute();

await db.schema
  .createView("InspirationView")

As you can see, in the last lines of code I'm creating a view. I want the Inspiration table to be reordered this way: the rows should be ordered by createdAt but the rows with the same traitId should be kind of like treated as only one row therefore one createdAt value. I think it's better to explain in with an example of ordered table.



content
createdAt
traitId




Test 1
8/5/2024
fha


Test 4
8/30/2024
fha


Test 2
8/10/2024
jk


Test 3
8/15/2024
lm



I tried different queries using with, partitionBy, orderBy, but I only managed to correctly order by, at the end, at most only one column.

Please show plain SQL table definition, sample data, your attempt at the query and its output, your expected output highlighting where it's wrong.

pg_dump --schema-only -t BigPaint -t Inspiration <database name> will give create table statements. They're much easier to understand.

To order by the minimum "createdAt" per group of same "traitId" without actually aggregating rows, use a window function:
SELECT content, "createdAt", "traitId"
FROM   "Inspiration"
ORDER  BY min("createdAt") OVER (PARTITION BY "traitId"), "traitId", "createdAt", content;

You don't have to include the same expression in the SELECT list.
I added "traitId", "createdAt", content as (optional) additional ORDER BY expressions to break ties and make the order deterministic.
Aside: avoid those mixed-case identifiers to make your life with Postgres easier. See:

Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?


It works expect for the order of the elements of the groups: the rows should instead independently be ordered by createdAt asc

@paolodelfino: See update.
